# the css profile randomly loading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the page

```
<head>
<title>here</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/redirect.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="load_here"></div>
...
```

and in the block load_here I load by jquery parts of the site

```
$(document).on("click",'#link_con',  function (){   
    $("#load_here").load("in_page/con.php");
        return false;
```

The problem that when I click on the link to load the site it load sometimes without css profile (I mean it open css profile but don't put the style on the blocks). And sometimes I click on the same link and everything work fine, what is that can be?

Comment: When you check your network panel you see the css file downloaded or is there an error?

Comment: yes it is loaded in style editor I see it, and there is no any error

Comment: Why not loading style in main page?

Comment: it what I do, I loading it in main page, and what i load is just a bunch of blocks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the mistake was actually in the jquery file, in a way of saving time I copy functions of loading pages and I forget to change in some of them the name of the link, in result there were 3 functions that ask deferent files  on the same link, as soon i fix it, everything get work properly.